# Issue with Inheritance Mapping of Doctrine and Symfony2?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I complete the work on symfony2 project that already implemented by another developer, my issue is with Inheritance Mapping, I have a declaration like that :

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Myapp\MyBundle\Entity\Repository\ProductRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="product")
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="inheritance", type="smallint")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap(
 *         { 0 = "Product",
 *           1 = "Hotel", 2 = "Attraction", 3 = "Tour",
 *           4 = "Car", "5" = "Transfer"})
 */
 abstract class Product
 {
 ....
```

and Transfer class :

```
/**
 * Transfer
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="transfer")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Myapp\MyBundle\Entity\Repository\TransferRepository")
 */
 class Transfer extends Product
 {
  ....
```

when I call Transfer class in my controller like that:

```
$em->getRepository('MyappMyBundle:Transfer')->findAll();
```

I get this error :

```
Method "name" for object "Myapp\MyBundle\Entity\Hotel" does not exist in MyappMyBundle:Transfer:index.html.twig at line 142
```

I don't know why symfony2 insist to call Hotel class even I call transfer class?

**EDIT**

Here the hotel class :

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="hotel")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Myapp\MyBundle\Entity\Repository\HotelRepository")
 */
 class Hotel extends Product
 {
```

index.html.twig

```
 ......
{% for t in transfers %}

                    <td>{{t.name}}</td>
 {% endfor %}
```

The only remark I can add, when I change hotel class by transfer class in product class, the call of transfer class works fine  and about hotel class he call transfer class?

```
  * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap(
  *         { 0 = "Product",
  *           1 = "Transfer", 2 = "Attraction", 3 = "Tour",
  *           4 = "Car", "5" = "Hotel"})
```

Comment: pls show your Hotel entity

Comment: and the  MyappMyBundle:Transfer:index.html.twig at line 142 too

Comment: As you said, you should not be getting hotel classes at all with your posted code.  Hence the objects being processed in your template are not coming from your posted query.  Recheck your code because you have other stuff going on.

Comment: check in the DiscriminatorMap annotation that you have double quoted the 5, try yo remove the `"`. Hope this help

Comment: @Cerad no all is in place I check a lot of the routes of posted query,I made changes above can you see it...

Comment: @YenneInfo I made some changes above...

Comment: You should not have a Repository on an abstract class. Furthermore, the best solution for heritance with an abstract class is to use @MappedSupperclass. Maybe try this instead.